# Wordpress изменить содержимое одинаковых плагинов на нескольких сайтах

Tags: php, wordpress, веб-программирование, wordpress-multisite

Проблема:
У меня есть 5 сайтов. На всех 5ти стоит один и тот же плагин, сожержимое которого мне нужно менять время от времени одинаково для всех 5. Возможно можно как-то засинхронизировать плагины, или сделать другим способом, чтоб можно было изменения внести в одном месте, и они применились к тому же плагину на всех 5ти сайтах.
Про Multisite я знаю, но не мой вариант.

Заранее благодарен.

Comment: Что значит "содержимое плагинов"?

Comment: Настройки и контент внутри плагина. Например : плагин галереи. Он у меня === на всех 5 сайтах. Я хочу изменить ссылку на изображение в этой галерее на всех 5 сайтах.

Comment: Тогда никак (если плагин этого не предусматривает). Ну т.е. надо писать отдельный скрипт или использовать инструменты автоматизации в браузере.

Comment: Попробуйте git говорят норм)